# how to properly create an image in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am fairly new to Docker.  I am creating a new image from a base image.  I am using the following Dockerfile.  I opened up the base image Dockerfile and copied the CMD.  Made my modifications and when I attempt to run the newly created image.  The container starts but the command that is executed shows up as
"kamailio -DD -E /bin/sh -c '["kamailio" "-DD" "-E"]'".  How can I get the entry command to be just "kamailio -DD -E"?  I have changed Entrypoint to CMD and no luck.  What am I missing?  Do I even need a CMD command if it is the same as the base image?

```
FROM kamailio/kamailio:5.2.8-stretch
WORKDIR ./
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5060
ENTRYPOINT ["kamailio -DD -E"]
```

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["kamailio", "-DD", "-E"]` is the entrypoint that is already defined in your base image. No need to re-define it.

Comment: Which command are you using to start the container?

Answer (score 0):

Your ENTRYPOINT has a wrong syntax. The sytax should be:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["kamilio", "-DD", "-E"]
```

That way, Docker will execute this command without the help of shell.

When `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` use string syntax, they get wrapped in sh -c so you have to use JSON syntax to avoid it. JSON syntax is in form of `["your_program", "param1", "param2", "...", "param n"]`. I guess that if you do your entrypoint like you did, Docker will parse it as a string syntax, therefore it will get wrapped in sh-c.

Also, when you use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together in Dockerfile, they should always be in JSON format.

EDIT: you can read more on this this topic here https://container.training/intro-selfpaced.yml.html#191

EDIT2: I always built my images through docker-compose the following way:

```
someContainer:
    build:
      context: ./folderContainingDockerFile
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "outside:5060"
# also try adding your entrypoint through docker-compose file like that:
    entrypoint: ["kamilio", "-DD", "-E"]
```

Comment: Same behavior when I put it in the ["kamailio", "-DD", "-E"].  The container continues to call the /bin/sh -c.

Comment: I believe my issue is that I am calling this from docker-compose.  The docker compose file is calling the image with just "build: .".  When I build the image and start the contianer with "docker run" it is now running fine, but not when I call it through docker-compose.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird. I edited the answer with a code snippet on how I do compose files when building images.